Blank PDF Issue when using TCPDF and Adobe Acrobat
I'm using TCPDF to create a PDF using TinyMCE to input the text. Then, I'm using TCPDF's method writeHTML to generate my PDF.
TINYMCE Editor
However, if Adobe Acrobat is activated in my browser, the document appears blank. If I deactivate Adobe Acrobat, the document works fine
PDF when Acrobat are activated
PDF when Acrobat are deactivated

You could save the PDF document to a file, and then inspect it more closely or use one of the many online PDF validators and see what they have to say. Please add any useful information you get in your question.
